# How to find highest sum of multiple items in Excel

Tags: excel, sum

Let's say we have a table like this in excel. How we can formulate finding the office with the highest total cost in the database?

[image]

I would also appreciate if you also know the answer in SQL syntax (in addition to Excel). (let's call this database dbo.cost

Thanks

Comment: Was about to give you an answer in Excel since you tagged it, then you excluded it with your last line.

Comment: I want the answer in Excel but if you ALSO know it in SQL, that would be a plus so I can learn both

Comment: In Excel, I'd advise you the `SUMIF()` function for determining the total cost per office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options for Excel:

Office 365:

`=INDEX(SORT(CHOOSE({1,2},SUMIFS(Table1[Cost],Table1[Office],Table1[Office]),Table1[Office]),,-1),1,2)`

All versions:

`=LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(0,1/(1+SUMIFS(Table1[Cost],Table1[Office],Table1[Office]))),Table1[Office])`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following for the SQL part (with SQL Server):

```
SELECT TOP 1 office, sum(cost) as Total  from Costs
GROUP BY Office
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, How we can do it to return the office with the highest cost?